# how can I mount container file to my local file system in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running elasticsearch:7.9.2 image.

I mount `./config`(local) to `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config`(container) by use this in my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
volumes:
   - ./config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config
```

I want the container file mount to my local file. Such as I have a.txt,b.txt and c.txt in container.I want to have a.txt,b.txt and c.txt in my local config directory after I run my container.
but  all contents of the container's directory get replaced by the contents of the host's directory.
How can I config this in docker-compose.yml? please help me!thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot mount single files but only complete volumes. So move those particular files in a separate directory and mount this directory as a volume into you container

Comment: But in this case the local file will rewrite the file in the container.I want the container file to  rewrite the local file.

Comment: Then create an empty directory, mount that as a volume and write the files from within the container. They will be available on the host then ...